# C# List.Sort gives unexpected results

Tags: c#, string, sorting

I have the following list of strings with more or less random strings:

```
    List<string> list= new List<string>();
    list.Add( "Apple" );
    list.Add( "Bubble" );
    list.Add( "Dino" );
    list.Add( "Common" );

    list.Sort();

    list.Add( "Aalborg" );

    list.Sort();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach ( string s in list) {
      sb.Append( s + " -> ");
    }

    MessageBox.Show( sb.ToString() );
```

I get

```
Apple -> Bubble -> Common -> Dino -> Aalborg ->
```

Instead of

```
Aalborg -> Apple -> Bubble -> Common -> Dino ->
```

As i expected

Solution:

list.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

Aa was read as Å due to cultureinfo

Comment: Why not `Aalborg -> Apple -> Bubble -> Common -> Dino` ?

Comment: how do you get that? I mean do you do a foreach and write to the console?

Comment: second 'a' from Aalborg i less than first 'p' from Apple

Comment: Aalborg is Danish spelling for Ålborg, so this sounds like a locale causing strange results.

Comment: Assuming the code exactly as you specify it, I'm seeing correct behaviour, not the behaviour you are mentioning.

Comment: It might be that it interprets Aa as Å. In that case, how do i change that?

Comment: @user2690219 Please supply an SSCCE so that we actually know what you are doing!

Comment: @user2690219 See my solution below. You should specify the string comparison to the sort method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely a locale problem,

try

```
list.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Compare

```
list.Sort(StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("da-dk"), false));
```

In the first case "Aa" is treated as the English letter "a" repeated twice. In the second example "Aa" is treated as Danish "Å" which is the last letter of the alphabet. So for some reason you string comparison must be Danish and the sorting is correct in this context.

Answer (score 4):

It is related to culture  info try this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Apple");
list.Add("Bubble");
list.Add("Dino");
list.Add("Common");
list.Add("Aalborg");

list.Sort(new CultureInfo("da-DK").CompareInfo.Compare);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",list)); //As in question

list.Sort(new CultureInfo("en-US").CompareInfo.Compare);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",list)); //As people expect
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a CultureInfo problem (or feature).

Everybody who answered, prefix yout code with:

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da");
```

for danish culture and you will get the same odd result as the autor of the question.

I found this solution after reading @feaster's comment on the original post.

To avoid this behaviour, use System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.